# I am taking data from front end in a textbox from the user which also includes new lines and using mongodb to store it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, api

The User enters data in a text box which also `includes new lines`.I am using mongodb to store the data and using node.js for backend.
I am hitting a route to store it and passing the values as params

When i have to display the data on frontend it does not show new lines but just gatheres all the data.
How to show new lines.

Take for eg **user enters-**

```
hello
all
the people
```

What **shows on frontend**

```
hello all the people
```

Comment: add css property `white-space: pre-line` to the display container

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that your are sending data into the `params` . In the `params` enter key i.e.s `\n` is not considered . Therefore when you fetch the data it appears as a `string` without any `\n` . 

**Solution**
Instead of sending data into the `params` . Send data into the `req.body` . as a result whenever you find that data , it will come with `/n` as example given below . And as out object comes with `/n` as we wanted . It will also rendered on html as we entered . 

**Example of data outcome**

```
"user": {
        "installation": [],
        "_id": "5d73792fd30b214c3250c2f1",
        "name": "PR \nBanna \n",
        "email": "pr@gmail.com",
        "password": "1234",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Here  i have saved `PR Banna` using enter key . You can see the difference.
(Note:- **/n will not considered as character in html so don't worry about that** ) 

Hope you get the point .